# Power LED with integrated charging for li-ion cell

Tags: led, batteries, integrated-circuit, battery-charging, battery-operated

I'm currently designing a BMS from scratch. I want to power a High Power LED with one single li-ion cell and through mains connection. The LED should shine when plugged in into the mains connection and simultaneously charge the li-ion battery (integrated charging). When plugged out from the mains connection the LED should shine uninterrupted and be powered by the li-ion cell. The li-ion cell should be removable. Does anyone know how I could realize it? I don't search for a circuit diagram, but just a general schematic.

Comment: This post is unfortunately fairly information-free. What is the cell voltage? What is the circuit doing other than just turning on a light? Does it even matter whether you regulate mains voltage if all you're doing is turning on a light? The minimal circuit would only need a half-rectifier and no regulator at all.

Comment: You intend on charging a Li-ion battery. Do you have a model number, or at least an amp-hour capacity in mind?

Comment: @Reinderien No. Again, I don't search for something specific, nor a circuit diagram. It should be applicable to different types of li-ion cells (LiPo, LiFePo4, LiCoO2,..) and different capacities.